# Map URL with port to URL without port for Docker?

Tags: docker, server, proxy

Assuming I want to have a lot of Docker containers with same port allocation.

```
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 wettyoss/wetty
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 wettyoss/wetty
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 wettyoss/wetty
...
```

Because I need to allocate each of the container to each user on a web application that used by tons of active users. So just allocating the only 65000 ports is not feasible/scalable idea. "URL" without ":port" scheme should be ideal.

So, what I want to achieve here can be expressed as a pseudo command like this:

```
docker run --rm -p 3000:/randomtokenforauser1 wettyoss/wetty # this should be accessed from your localhost/randomtokenforauser1 
docker run --rm -p 3000:/randomtokenforauser2 wettyoss/wetty # localhost/randomtokenforauser2
docker run --rm -p 3000:/randomtokenforauser3 wettyoss/wetty # localhost/randomtokenforauser3
...
```

So, Is something like this possible using docker or something, for Docker containers?

Comment: You'd need the same techniques you'd need to implement this without Docker; Docker doesn't have any special support here (`docker run -p` doesn't know anything about HTTP paths).  You will probably hit scaling problems for having thousands of processes before you start to hit port-exhaustion problems, though.

Comment: You can implement your idea with a reverse-proxy. Although I agree with David, there  might be a better design for the application.

Comment: So, I'd better think an other idea since it, allocating one full docker container process to one user, is cost-ineffective?

Comment: But @anemyte, I pondered over about that also, but really have no idea what I can do, what kind of technology, framework, library I can use. I'd really appreciate if you know workaround for this issue.

Comment: You can use `nginx` as a reverse-proxy. You can make a config for nginx that will extract part of the URL and use this part to select target container on the network. I can drop you an example later.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a reverse-proxy that selects the target container using part of the URL:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
---
version: "3"
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    environment:
      CONFIG: |
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
        server {
          listen 80;

          # $$ is an escape sequence for docker-compose, so that it will not treat it as a variable
          location ~ ^/(.+?)/?$$ {
            proxy_pass http://$$1:3000/wetty;
          }
        }

    ports:
    - 80:80
    entrypoint: ""
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - echo "$$CONFIG" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && /docker-entrypoint.sh nginx -g "daemon off;"

  foo: &wetty
    image: wettyoss/wetty

  bar: *wetty
  baz: *wetty
```

In the example above only service `proxy` exposes it's port. Your client containers (foo, bar, baz) are not directly available. This piece of `nginx` configuration:

```
location ~ ^/(.+?)/?$ {
  proxy_pass http://$1:3000/wetty;
}
```

takes out first part of a request URL and passes the request to the container with the matching name. That is, if you navigate to `localhost/foo`, your request will be forwarded to the container `foo`, `localhost/bar` -> `bar`, and so on.

This config is a proof of concept: it's enough to handle first request but consecutive requests will likely fail. Making a fully functional config will require a lot of time and a good understanding of application routes and user interaction. Feel free to play with this example but as I said, you had better to look for an architecture more efficient than 'one user, one container'.